# Live Wallpaper not setting

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I have written a live wallpaper for android it works fine in the live wallpaper picker but will not set when i click set wallpaper.  I know my launcher supports live wallpapers because I have one running, and the same thing happens on both my phone and the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

A little more information on your issue would be nice actually so i can give you only general advices:

- don't forget to add `android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER"` to your manifest;
- use Log Cat to see if application was started at all, put some
  Log.v("my wallpaper", "Service initialized") instructions in your
  code.
- remove any code that can block execution of your app. I once had `Debug.waitForDebugger` instruction which was ok in debug mode but blocked installation in release mode.